# Why don't closures called from non-pointer values ​be added to slices correctly?

Tags: pointers, go

This is the argument in `go1.12.3 linux/amd64`.

Added two closures to the slice `s` containing the function through the variable `x`.
The closure is obtained by a method with a pointer receiver of type `T`.
Added two closures to the slice s containing the function through the variable x.
The closure is obtained by a method with a pointer receiver of type T.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type T struct {
    X int
}

func (t *T) f() func() {
    return func() { fmt.Println(t.X) }
}

func good() {
    s := []func(){}

    x := &T{1}
    s = append(s, x.f())

    x = &T{2}
    s = append(s, x.f())

    s[0]() // => 1
    s[1]() // => 2
}

func bad() {
    s := []func(){}

    x := T{1}
    s = append(s, (&x).f())  // Even if it rewrites to append(s, x.f()), the result is the same.

    x = T{2}
    s = append(s, (&x).f())

    s[0]() // => 2 WHY!?
    s[1]() // => 2
}

func main() {
    good()
    bad()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/j-818FZELQb

Of the above two functions, `good()` works as expected.
In good `s[0]()` executes `T{1}.f()()`, and s `s[1]()` executes `T{2}.f()()`.
However, `bad()` runs `s[0]()` and `s[1]()` run `T{2}.f()()`.
Even though I added the element to the slice without overwriting it!

I have no idea what caused this behavior.
Didn't the variable `x` have a value of type `T` instead of a pointer to a value of type `T`?
Or do I not know the call specification of append?

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in bad you have just *one* variable `x` of type T and *one* variable has just *one* address and thus your slice s contains always the same function working on the same variable which has value 2 when you start calling the functions.

(In good you have *two* different variables of type T. You reuse a variable (x) of type *T but you still have two *different* T with different values.)

Comment: In `bad()` there is certainly only one address.
However, `(&x).f()` is evaluated in the first `append()`.
So it looks like the 0th element of the slice contains `(&T{1}).F()`.
Is `(&T{1}) F()` stored in slice `s[0]` no longer irrelevant to variable `x`?
After that, the value of x changes with `x = T{2}`, but I do not know why it affects `(&T {1}).F()` already stored in the slice.
Is the second argument of append evaluated late? In that case, I can somehow see that `s[0]()` and `s[1]()` have the same value.

Comment: @Maxy Your thinking is _far_ _too_ _complex. In Bad you have one variable `x`. A "variable" is some place in memory. After `x = T{1}` that memory contains a 1. After `x = T{2}` that memory contains 2. Your x has has just address: `&x`. That you do some magic with method values is just obfuscation: Your slice contains function which take a memory address as their argument. This memory address is the one of x. You have just one x, you have just one address and both functions are called with the same argument, that address.

Comment: @Maxy Note that it is **wrong** to say "the slice contains (&T{1}).F()": The slice contains "the f operating on the address of x". `f` is defined with a pointer receiver and `&x` is that receiver. The _value_ which is stored in the `x` is _not_ involved here. The slice s stores a function working on a memory address. What this memory address contains is not stored in the slice and can be changed whenever you like.

Comment: Some more comments: 1. All this is unrelated to closures (your code does not contain any closure). Thinking about a method value as a closure is wrong, a method value is _not_ a closure. 2. All this is unrelated to slices and append. It just makes your code more complicated. The difference between good and bad is: good uses two different variables (= areas of memory) while bad uses just one variable (memory area). Both (good and bad) reuse a name `x` but good reuses it for a different _memory_ _address_ while bad reuses it for a different _value_.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and some notes!
I read the comments and reviewed the variables and calls again.
With this question, I understand that slices are irrelevant and only receiver obfuscation and pointer variable problems.
As a result, I thought that it would be better to call a point receiver basically with a pointer variable.